# UI5 Control - How to use xml template instead of renderer

Tags: sapui5

I want to use a xml template instead of the JavaScript renderer inside a custom control.
Is that possible?

I read that [XML Composite Control](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/05/25/create-your-first-xml-composite-control/) was the solution but it's now [deprecated](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13359130/sapuicorexmlcomposite-deprecated.html)...

Comment: I think the answer is in your second link. It didn't perform well and thus was deprecated. Deprecated means you could theoretically still use it, but who knows for how long.

Comment: I thought there could be another way...

Comment: I also wish it was as easy as in Vue.js to build new components. But to be fair UI5 contains a huge amount of controls out of the box.